# Como ativar a compactação de recursos com gzip ou deflate no meu site?

Tags: htaccess, otimização, gzip, pagespeed-insights

Não consigo ativar a compactação de recursos com `gzip` ou `deflate` no meu site. No server a opção já está habilitada e no `.htaccess` também, só que o page speed ainda continua falando que não está ativada a compactação `gzip`.

Comment: Qual o servidor? Apache? Ou seria lighttpd? Ou mesmo nginx? Eu está rodando um servlet em um container?